# Overstay in UK 8 years ago - with mention in passport

Tags: uk, overstaying, removal

I over stayed in the UK (Scotland) for more than a year and while returning to India, they wrote (handwritten) 1515/a in my passport. It happened 8 years ago.

Will there be still any record of that overstay?

Comment: Note: a person can only overstay in the United Kingdom, individual countries within the UK have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Did you return on your own or were you forcibly removed?

Answer (score 16):

**they remarked (handwritten) 1515/a in my passport.**

The 151a form is the old removal notice, it was replaced in 2014. When they serve you with a removal notice ([151/a, 151/b, or the current RED.0001](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424253/Chapter50_non_EEA_V12__external_final_.pdf)) they can also make an annotation in your passport. The [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424253/Chapter50_non_EEA_V12__external_final_.pdf) informs us that the overstayer whose breach is more than 90 days must be served, there is no discretionary latitude.

Unlike [refusal notices](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusal), **removal notices** are massively formulaic and there's usually no information of any value to go on for the future. You should hang on to it because it has your case number.  It's the right-most column in the screen shot below...

[image]

**Will there be still any record with them?**

Yes, they keep biometrics for 12 years, but for an overstayer there is no limit.  You need to declare a removal if there is less than 10 years since the date of the incident. If you are considering answering 'no' on the application form, you will get caught.

Note: 2016 minus 8 gives 2008. The government made transitional provisions for overstayers who were caught prior to November 2008 that you may be able to benefit from.  That discussion is off-topic here (IMHO) and best taken up with a solicitor. There are solicitors in London who specialise in word-crafting an explanation that the decision-makers will look favourably on. Alternatively you can ask on the [Law site](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Couldn't the OP just wait for another couple of years and answer 'no' on the visa application?

Comment: @JonathanReez, absolutely YES. it will fall off the grid and the OP can deny a prior removal :)  But they will STILL have a record of it.

Comment: I'm not sure I would answer 'Yes' to that question, it sounds like the poster voluntarily left the country. From his description he wasn't deported, remove or required to leave, he just left of his own accord.

Comment: Of course his chances of getting a visa, which for anybody start at about 25% have probably fallen to <1%

Comment: @mcfedr, that comment might make the core of a great answer that serves as a counterpoint and gives the OP a full spectrum of answers. You can flesh out your comment and add the references (it's ok to duplicate my links). If it makes sense at all, I will up vote it, and since it's (presumably) what the OP wants to hear, it will probably get accepted as well.

Comment: If an official wrote 151/a in the questioner's passport, though, then I guess the questioner should be very sure that a removal notice wasn't issued/served before writing that they have never been required to leave? Even if you're already walking hurriedly towards the door at the moment when the UK government yells "you're required to leave" at you, they presumably still deem that having been required to leave. Or not?

Comment: @SteveJessop yes, you've got it. From a strict legal viewpoint, 'voluntarily' diminishes once 90 days have elapsed. It is no longer an opportunity for the person unless the Home Office gives permission to leave voluntarily (which doesn't happen). That's the case despite the individual exiting the country on their own in a way that *appears* to be voluntary. The OP needs to declare it. And the Border Force does not make an endorsement in someone's passport just willy-nilly :)

Comment: @mcfedr, not sure how you came up with a probability number? I think everyones application is mutually exclusive and probabilities would depend on their individual histories.

Comment: I'll be honest, I made it up completely, and probably exaggerated a bit, but my experience of applying for peoples visa's is terrible. I am a UK citizen, but have often helped friends apply. I have often come away thinking that the application is less important than the political feeling of the day and probably a couple of dice.

Comment: @GayotFow The border force does put stuff in your passport for all sorts of reasons, overturned refusal stamps getting left in are a particular favourite of mine.
You may be right that the OP was strictly required to leave. I don't know much about this situation, but the OPs description didn't make it sound like he was required to leave.

Comment: @mcfedr from time-to-time the mods come through and delete comment threads. It would be a shame if your ideas were lost in a bit bucket because they were not presented as an answer.

Comment: @GayotFow I really hope you are messing me with :) My 'ideas' are really just me taking the opportunity to have a rant about the Border force and really don't constitute any serious advise, which without any understanding of 151a I am not in a position to give.

Comment: @mcfedr Honestly, I'm not messing with you. I lack only 4 points for the Sportsmanship Badge.

Comment: @GayotFow Well I'll humour you :) Got to get some points in a new network somehow )

Answer (score 7):

I would be very surprised if they don't keep a record of your overstay.

And when you are applying for a visa, I would read very carefully any paper work you were given and think carefully about how you answer the question about deportation on the form

[image: deportation question]

I would tend to feel that, whilst you want to avoid putting 'yes', you also definitely don't want to lie about it.

Either way, you want to look for lots of 'documents' that might be able to support your case that you wont overstay again. The Border force isn't known for its good humour, any excuse to not give a visa is a good excuse for them.